# how to set custom method with rightnavagation Button in NavBar

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, uinavigationbar

I want set my custom method "Home" with RightNavagation button how should I?
  My code

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DontWorryAboutThis" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(home:)];

[barButton setImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"home_btn.png"]];
[self.navigationItem setRightBarButtonItem:barButton];
```

Know I want to link this method with it.

```
-(IBAction)home{

   MainViewController *main=[[MainViewController alloc]
                           initWithNibName:@"MainViewController" bundle:nil];
   [self.navigationController pushViewController:main animated:YES];
}
```

how should I Do this please help me out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to change

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DontWorryAboutThis" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(home:)];
```

in

```
UIBarButtonItem *barButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"DontWorryAboutThis" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(home)];
```

Answer (score 0):

compare your selector @selector(**home:**) with your action -(IBAction)**home**

See the missing colon in your action?
Change your action to

```
- (IBAction)home:(id)sender
```